# Loading partial view into the main view AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view, which I plan to include in different pages.

I tried out the following to load the partial view but the view doesn't display the values stored in the model.

**Angular controller:**

```
//This gets the required data as JSON
AdminService.getSettings(function (callback) {
    $scope.attributes = callback;
    $scope.groups = _.groupBy($scope.attributes, "Group");
    $scope.previous = angular.copy($scope.attributes);
    //This gets the partial view and adds to the main view
    CommonService.SettingsListView_get(function (callback) {  
        angular.element('#settingsList').html(callback);
    });
});
```

**MVC Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SettingsList()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

**View: Main**

```
<body ng-app="AngularAdmin" ng-cloak>
<div ng-controller="SettingsCtrl" id="top" ng-init="init()">
    <br />
    <div id="settingsList" >

    </div>
```

**View:partial**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div style="padding:5px 0"><button ng-click="updateAttributes(attributes)" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Update Settings</button></div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary" data-ng-repeat="(items, item) in groups" ng-style="$index < 11 ? panelStyle[$index] : commonPanelStyle">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-style="$index < 11 ? panelHeaderStyle[$index] : commonPanelHeaderStyle">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#accordion{{$index}}" ng-style="anchorStyle">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    {{ items }}
                </h4>
            </a>
        </div>

    <div id="accordion{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body" ng-style="$index < 11 ? panelBodyStyle[$index] : commonPanelBodyStyle">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Attribute</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th>Taken from</th>
                    <th>Editable</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="i in item">
                    <td> {{ i.AttributeName }} </td>
                    <td> {{ i.Description }} </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" ng-model="i.Value" class="form-control" ng-disabled="{{!i.Editable}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td><span ng-bind="i.TakenFrom | settingsfilter">{{ Heritage }}</span> </td>
                    <td><span ng-class="i.Editable | activefilter : { icon1 : 'glyphicon-edit', icon2 : 'glyphicon-remove'}" class="glyphicon" style="font-weight: bolder"></span></td>
                    <td><span ng-click="deleteAttribute(i.AttributeGuid)" ng-class="i.TakenFrom | deletefilter : 1" class="glyphicon" style="font-weight: bolder"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button style="float:right" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateAttributes(item)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Update <em>{{ items }}</em> Settings </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Issue:**
I can't display the settings data I can see `{{ items }}` and nothing else in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way to achieve this is to create a "settingsList" directive and set the templateUrl to the url of the partial view. You could get rid of this:

```
CommonService.SettingsListView_get(function (callback) {  
        angular.element('#settingsList').html(callback);
    });
```

and replace this:

```
<div id="settingsList" >

    </div>
```

with this:

```
<div settingsList></div>
```

If for some reason this isn't possible in your situation, try changing your controller code the following (you'll need to inject the $compile service):

```
CommonService.SettingsListView_get(function (callback) {  
        var element = angular.element(callback);
        $compile(element)($scope);
        angular.element('#settingsList').append(element);
        $scope.digest();
    });
```

Comment: If you hit a break point in your controller, $scope.groups contains exactly what you think it should? ie - an object whose keys are strings and whose values are arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

this code working good :

```
CommonService.SettingsListView_get(function (callback) {  
        var element `enter code here`= angular.element(callback);
        $compile(angular.element('#settingsList').append(element))($scope);
});
```